# How to implement Stack Overflow's "are you a human" feature?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

On this site if you do too many clicks or post comments too fast or something like that you get redirected to the "are you a human" screen.  Does anybody know how to do something similar?

Comment: Hey people, this doesn't belong on Meta! This is about verifying someone is human. They are just using SO as an example

Comment: @Earlz: That's not what the original question said, especially given the question title.

Comment: This type of feature is known as annoying.

Comment: Or are you dancer? :)

Comment: +1 for the killers reference!

Comment: @Omu - as you've added a bounty, perhaps you could outline what the answers that are already posted are missing for you? Otherwise one of us will just end up with the bounty for providing an answer that doesn't give you what you actually want... :)

Comment: well, it's kinda simple, I want to do the same stuff as stackoverflow did: just try to post a comment to 5 answers in 5 seconds and you'll see :)

Comment: That I gathered, but,... Which bit are the current answers not answering? From what I can see, all of them answer part/all of the question, depending on how it's interpreted. Mine answers the "how to detect" bit, others answer the "how to do the page you get sent to", and some more answer the "how to implement the redirect" and finally there's answers to "how do I implement the detection"... What else is missing? :)

Comment: In other words, I'll happily take the bounty, just tell me what my answer's missing for you =)

Comment: implementation in asp.net mvc ;)

Comment: Omu, thank you for the points, I have include one more link with source code for checking the dos attact. Actually I have use and test all, from what I see now I use the new one I type.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's a very good link you posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very nice **Captcha Control** for asp.net that first of all you need

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/CaptchaControl.aspx

Then you can use it together with this idea that try to find the **dos attacks**

http://weblogs.asp.net/omarzabir/archive/2007/10/16/prevent-denial-of-service-dos-attacks-in-your-web-application.aspx

be ware of a bug in this code in line if( context.Request.Browser.Crawler ) return false;, its must return true, or totally remove it for sure.

**and make it your compination for the clicks, or submits.**

If a user make too many clicks on a period of time, or many submits, then you simple open the capthaControl, and if the clicks are by far too many, then triger the dos attact. This way you have 2 solution in one, Dos attact prevent, with captcha at the same time.

I have made somthing similar my self, but I have change the source code of both, a lot to feet my needs.

One more interesting link for a different code for the dos attack.

http://madskristensen.net/post/Block-DoS-attacks-easily-in-ASPNET.aspx

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 10):

It's almost certainly a heuristic that tries to "guess" that a user is some form of automated process, rather than a person, for example:

- More than "x" requests to do the same thing in a row
- More than "x" actions in a "y" period of time

Ordinarily the "x" and "y" values would be formulated to be ones that it would be unlikely for a "real person" to do, like:

- Editing the same answer 5 times in a row
- Downvoting 10 questions within 1 minute

Once you've got your set of rules, you can then implement some code that checks them at the start of each request, be it in a method that's called in Page_Load, something in your masterpage, something in the asp.net pipeline, that's the easy bit! ;)

Comment: How did you post an answer on a migrated question!?

Comment: @Earlz, I undeleted my answer. I'm assuming that the migration process deleted it. As I disagreed with the migration, and the site gave me an "undelete" link, I "protested" against the migration by undeleting my answer.

Comment: @Earlz, I'm sure it probably is, but it made me happy! ;)

Comment: +1 yes, I think I saw some of the code on meta. They just cache the user+ip+action and set it to expire for whatever period of time. It would be madness to hit database for all these checks.

Comment: @Aristos's answers has a link to an implementation of this, and it also uses the cache, and setting it to expire

Comment: @Omu - It looks to me like an asp.net webforms control, so not something you'd really use in MVC? :) It might give you some ideas for an MVC implementation though!

Answer (score 2):

At a guess...

Write a HTTP handler that records requests and store them in session.

When a new request comes in, check to see how many requests are stored (and expire old ones).

If the amount of requests in the past few minutes exceeds a given threshold, redirect the user.

If you're doing this in ASP.NET webforms, you could do this check on the site master page, ( or write a `IHttpHandler`).

If you're using an MVC framework, you could write a base controller that does this check for every action.

With rails, you could write a `before_request` filter.

With asp.net MVC, you could write a `[ActionFilterAttribute]` attribute

Answer (score 2):

You should have a session to track the user activity.

In session you can have counter for commenting and posting like:

(pseudo code instead of C#, sorry :)

```
if (post_event) {

    posts_during_1_minute_interval++;

    if (time_now-reference_time > 1_minute) {
    reference_time = time_now;
    posts_during_1_minute_interval=0;
    }
}
...
if (posts_during_1_minute_interval > 10) redirect("/are-you-human.htm");
```

where on are-you-human.htm page you can have [recaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/), as they have here on StcakOverflow.com

see also:https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/are-you-a-human-being/

Answer (score 1):

just check how many hit / minutes you get from a specific ip or session or whatever and decide what are your preferred threshold and your good to go

Comment: Just be sure that the time period is right b/c otherwise quick users will be very annoyed and you might drive away some of the more useful users.

Comment: Or users from an organisation that uses a single proxy to access the internet

Answer (score -2):

I'd also check the user agent header of the request - if it doesn't look like a popular browser (or is empty) then throw the "are you a human?" page.

Comment: Why be cruel to those of us who browse with links?!?

Comment: Links being linx (the text-based browser?) If so I'm fairly sure that sends a proper user-agent header, so wouldn't be affected.  I'm talking about headers like GoogleBot, MSNSpider etc.

Comment: This is a really bad idea - it's what leads to things like apps that require ie6 because ie7 was not a valid browser at the time, or what paypal does if you try to buy something using a mobile browser.

Comment: @Tom - the original question was how to tell if someone is a human.  It's easy to tell using the User-Agent header if someone is using an actual browser, or if it's a bot.  Yes some nasty bots make themselves look like a browser, so this has to be used in combination with other security tactics - but that's the same in any case - IT or non-IT related.  You don't just rely on a lock on your door to keep people out.  You also have an alarm system. And a locked gate etc.

Comment: It's easy to tell if it is a known browser or a known bot, but relying on that will cause problems with either unknown browsers or unknown bots. Since the known bots are things like google that you want to give full access, and the ones you need to block will pretend to be browsers, you are introducing bugs without gaining any security.

In terms of physical security it's more like nailing the locked door shut and leaving an open window next to it.